# How to add Circle shape in a rectangle div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to add a circle shape in the middle of a rectangle div like this:

[image: capture1]

Here is the html:

```
<div class="p-5 mb-3 mainInfo"></div>
```

And with this CSS:

```
.mainInfo{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .01rem round #e0e1ed;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #585CA1;
}
```

And this is how the rectangle div looks like:

[image: capture2]

So how can I add circle in the middle of this div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this by `absolute` positioning and `::before` selector.
::before height and background color is same as .mainInfo container which it makes the circle shadow hidden inside the container.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainInfo">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainInfo{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .01rem round #e0e1ed;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #585CA1;
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.circle:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 15em;
    height: 5em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[**Link to the Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yswo1bhn/6/)

Comment: Great, can you please take a look t this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433589/how-to-place-image-inside-of-a-parent-div-properly