# How to place image inside of a parent div properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="p-5 mb-3 mainInfo">
           <div class="circle"><img src="https://nanoclub.ir/images/cut.png"></div>
</div>
```

And result goes like this:

[image]

However, it should be showing inside the div like this:

[image]

And here is the CSS:

```
    .mainInfo{
        background-color: #fff;
        border: .01rem round #e0e1ed;
        border-radius: 20px;
        color: #585CA1;
        height:50px;
    }
    .circle {
        position:absolute;
        width:150px;
        height:170px;
        border-radius:50%;
        background:#fff;
        right:100px;
        top:40%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
```

So how can I place the image inside `circle` div properly like the expected image?

Comment: You only positioned the circle, you also need to position the `img` inside the circle div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by `absolute` positioning and `::before` selector. Also I added border radius to the image with a max width.

HTML:

```
<div class="mainInfo">
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mainInfo{
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .01rem round #e0e1ed;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #585CA1;
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  margin-top: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 17px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}

.circle:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 15em;
    height: 5em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #fff;
}

.circle img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 85%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 200;
}
```

[**Link to the Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz3bs7hc/)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answers, but how to add text into the left section and right section? I would really appreciate if you answer me, I really need this...

Comment: Glad to help. You can use absolute positioning again OR change the .mainInfo justify-content property to space-between then use absolute centering for the circle.

Comment: Please would you mind check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434672/how-to-add-text-into-rounded-rectangle-separating-by-a-circle